# How to add a button in react native environment?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

could you please tell me how to add button in view using react native .

here is my code
https://rnplay.org/apps/0TPePA

can I used this this
https://npmcdn.com/react-native-button@1.6.0
in my demo ?

I need to add button in my view here is code

```
  class First extends Component {
    render (){

     return (<View><Text>"hello"</Text> 
         </View>
            ) 
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a button yourself is quite simple. You can use toucableopacity and the onPress method attached to it.

Put the following in your render method

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onButtonPress}>
<Text>Button Text</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And put this in a react function.

```
_onButtonPress: function () {
    console.log ("Button has been pressed");
}
```

To make it look more like a button you can add styling directly to the `<Text style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', etc...}}`